# Packet Sniffer Sniffs Packet Twice

Tags: python, packet-sniffers

```
RECEIVER_PORT = 5005 # target port
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.ntohs(3))
    while True:
        raw_data, addr = conn.recvfrom(65536)
        dest_mac, src_mac, eth_proto, data = ethernet_frame(raw_data)

        if eth_proto == 8:
            (version, header_length, ttl, proto, src, target, data) = ipv4_Packet(data)

            # Sniff UDP Communication between the sender and the receiver
            if proto == 17:
                src_port, dest_port, length, data = udp_seg(data)
                if dest_port == RECEIVER_PORT: 
                    print(TAB_2 + 'Source Port: {}, Destination Port: {}, Length: {}'.format(src_port, dest_port, length))
```

My python packet sniffer monitors communication between two applications: a sender and a receiver. It is particularly interested when a packet is being sent to the receiver. In addition, the receiver ONLY receives packets from the sender. Whenever a packet is sent from the sender to the receiver, my program executes "if dest_port == RECEIVER_PORT" twice, and I do not understand why? I want my program to execute that statement once, since I only send one packet from the sender to the receiver.

Comment: There's usually a confusion in how sending works, as the packets tend to pass from the sender twice through the network stack IIRC. Meaning if you're sending something, you'll see it being transmitted through the socket layer and you'll see it on the NIC leaving as well. This only happens on the sender side and you'll have to check the session if you're using TCP to avoid replays. At least from my experience using raw sockets.

Comment: @Torxed I am using UDP. Would the same apply to UDP?

Comment: Not really unless the protocol that goes over the line has some form of transmission id of sorts. I mean there's probably a neat way around it but I've just never found it, I just ended up with the same issue you did. Altho, humm, maybe I did solve it o0 Could you try something? Could you see if you experience the same issue with [this](https://github.com/Torxed/Scripts/blob/master/python/Laboratory/switch.py) code? It sets the socket/interface in a promisc mode (old code i found/wrote a few years ago, don't remember if it fixed it). Skip a lot of the code as it's for parsing packets :)

Comment: @Torxed! Thanks! Your code actually suits my project better I think. However, I have a few questions (I'm new to the whole networking thing). My program is currently hosted on just my local machine. My concern currently is I'm just doing test on my local computer with just local host IP and port number. So my question is, will I even be able sniff communication between the sender and receiver in promiscious mode since the IP and MAC addresses between the applications will be them same? I'm wondering if promiscious mode is even applicable, since i'm only concerned with the src_port and dest_prt

Comment: @Torxed my project is suppose to have three computers hooked up with an ethernet switch. The attacker, sender, and receiver will all be hosted on different computers. The attacker is also suppose to monitor the network via promiscious mode. I just don't have the 3 computers and ethernet switch (cause of COVID) so I'm trying to just build/test the my program on 1 computer.

Comment: It will sort of work, but I'd recommend setting up a VirtualBox/VMWare workstation/libvirt lab setup with three machines on a isolated network. Because you'll go mad debugging three scenarios from one machine. And for obvious reasons this will only work on local LAN's not over the internet or anything. This is a pretty complex project. You might be better off using python+tcpdump https://github.com/agnosticdev/Network-Capture or scapy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214806/discussion-between-logic-bomb-walter-and-torxed).